# Twitter online accounts, is authorized and then it needs to be authorized again

Tags: 13.04, online-accounts, twitter

I have twitter added to my online accounts and about once a day it needs to be granted access, is there any way to keep it granted always.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen with other IM accounts including on Ubuntu. Totally delete the account from your Ubuntu IM (Pidgin, whatever) and create a new occurrence of the same account. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried that yesterday and had no luck with that, cause today right before I posted this question it had come up to grant access to twitter.